# How make like this shape in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

Hi there, I tried many times to make a shape in Photoshop to show the stats/activity in design. SO I wanna know how to make such a shape in photoshop by shape tool .Thanks

Comment: Depends a little on your PS version. If you have an older version of PS (CS5 or earlier), you might be better off doing it in Illustrator and Import it back to PS. Very doable with CS5, but a bit more difficult, especially if you want to keep it as a `Shape layer`.

Answer (score 3):

This Is pretty easy, You can do it this way

Create a shape width shape tool (border and no fill), now go to property and "**set line cap type for stroke**" to **round** and delete the unwanted path or curve
here's the demonstration

[image]